# Text search in similar clauses that contains misspelled words

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene, fuzzy-search

We need to extract some information from a free text clause. Let's think we have a clause about a a ship leaving a port and going another port. The same meaning can be expressed in several ways like this:

```
    The Ship A departed from the Port X on Monday, to reach Port Y.
    The ship A left the Port X on Monday to reach Port Y.
    The Ship A arrived to Port Y, it left Port X on Monday.
    Port Y will be visited by Ship A which left Port X on Monday.
```

And also author might misspell words:

```
   departed -> deported, dearted, depared, departeed, deparded
   reach -> reaach, rech, rreach, reac
   arrived -> arived, arivved, arrivd
```

So what is the best way to extract "Ship A", "Port X", "Port Y", "Monday" words from those clauses?
Programming language is Java.
Shall we use reqular expressions or lucene fuzzy search or elasticsearch etc.
Or some combination of them?

Thank you

Comment: You can use NER (Named Entity Recognize) libraries for hetting information from free text. you can check [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/). Also, there are other NER labraries available. In java, you can create dictinory and used for geeting entity from text.

Comment: Thank you @SagarPatel, I'll definetely look into NER libraries.

Answer (score 1):

This program finds the information that you need in the sample strings and puts it in the right order. Its needs further work to cope with mispellings. We could also expand the day regex to accept dates.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(getPorts("The Ship A departed from the Port X on Monday, to reach Port Y."));
    System.out.println(getPorts("The ship A left the Port X on Monday to reach Port Y."));
    System.out.println(getPorts("The Ship A arrived to Port Y, it left Port X on Monday."));
    System.out.println(getPorts("Port Y will be visited by Ship A which left Port X on Monday."));
     }
     
     public static String getPorts(String sentence){
         String port1 = "unknown";
         String port2 = "unknown";
         String ship = "unknown";
         String day = "unknown";
         Pattern pattern;
         if (sentence.matches(".*(arriv|reach|visit).*(left|depart).*")) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<port2>[Pp]ort\\s\\w+).*(?<port1>[Pp]ort\\s\\w+)");} 
         else if (sentence.matches(".*(left|depart).*(arriv|reach|visit).*")) {
            pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<port1>[Pp]ort\\s\\w+).*(?<port2>[Pp]ort\\s\\w+)");}
      else { return "not matched";}
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
      while (matcher.find()) {
          port2 = matcher.group("port2");
          port1 = matcher.group("port1");
      }
      pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<ship>[Ss]hip\\s\\w+)");
      matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
      while (matcher.find()) {
          ship = matcher.group("ship");
      }
      pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<day>(Mon|Tues?|Wed(nes)?|Thu(rs)?|Fri|Sat(ur)?|Sun)(day)?)");
      matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
      while (matcher.find()) {
          day = matcher.group("day");
      }
      return ship + " sailing from " + port1 + " to " + port2 + " on " + day +"." ;
}   
}
```

output

```
Ship A sailing from Port X to Port Y on Monday.
ship A sailing from Port X to Port Y on Monday.
Ship A sailing from Port X to Port Y on Monday.
Ship A sailing from Port X to Port Y on Monday.
```

Tested at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Kendle, your solution for these example inputs is ok, but all input clauses will be dynamic. I mean an author might use "entered to Port Y" instead of "arrived to Port Y". So i think we need more like Named Entity Recognition / NLP approach like Sagar Patel said. Upvoted your answer though.

Comment: Thank you mtorak : be free to post the answer to your own problem when you get it working. I don't know NER/NLP and would be interested to see how you apply it. :-)

Comment: I think need to create a custom training data set. I would be happy to share it when i come up with a solution. Cheers.